# Image Placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have defined the image tag with a background color so that if there is no image the color should show but still the broken image icon is showing how to remove that ?

I dont want to make the page bulky by adding jquery or any framework , also i cant add any kind of divs to images because the site is almost done.

Found the answer with only javascript

```
function ImgError(source){
source.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
source.onerror = "";
return true;
}

<img src="someimage.png" onerror="ImgError(this);"/>
```

Comment: You can assign the `alt` attribute e.g. `<img src="http://www.dummy.com/dummy.png" alt="my cute cat" />` then the alternative text will appear with the background color you have applied.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you can hide that using following:

```
<img
  src="my.png"
  onerror="this.style.display='none'"
/>
```

you can display another image if image not found as follow:

```
<img src="my.png" onerror="this.src = 'image-not-found.png';" />
```

Comment: I'd suggest visibility:hidden instead of display:none if you don't want it to affect layout. Also, note my point about wrapping it in a div if you need to have a background color display when the image doesn't load.

Comment: @NickLockwood ya thats also a way

Comment: i cant add anything manually to the image tags there are many tags all around the site .

Comment: @PradyumnaSharma you can add attributes dynamically

Comment: @PradyumnaSharma if you can't add anything to the tags manually, and javascript is out of the question, then I believe you're stuck with the browser's default behaviour.

Comment: I dont want to load jquery java script is ok

Comment: you can write javascript  like  <img id="myimage" src="my.png"/> <script>
          
        document.getElementById('myimage').setAttribute('onerror', "this.src = 'image-not-found.png';");
      
        </script>

Comment: Sweet solution, I'm into into coding web applications for years but didn't knew of the onerror-attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution but **be careful**: if you don't reset the error callback and, for some unexpected reasons, your 'image-not-found.png' is not found then your app/site will start throwing a loop of infinite errors.

Answer (score 9):

Solution with 1x1 empty png

```
        function ImgError(source){
            empty1x1png = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQI12NgYAAAAAMAASDVlMcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
            source.src = "data:image/png;base64," + empty1x1png;
            source.onerror = "";
            return true;
        }

        <img src="someimage.png" onerror="ImgError(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to use, literally, a placeholder blank image. This is generally used for sprites but I think you could use this as well.

What you do is, you create a 1x1 px blank gif image with transparency enabled, direct the "src" atrribute to the blank.gif and give the images via the css background-image property.
Therefore, even if the background image is not found, it won't show the broken link image.

Comment: You should be aware though there is a minor downside to this. The extra image request ofcourse. You can leverage this by utilizing sprites wherever possible, hence decreasing the total number of image requests.

Comment: I would create a base64 representation of the 1px by 1px and store it in the JavaScript.  This would eliminate the network request.  Base64 images are a bit less efficient but at 1px by 1px it will not matter.  Also, if you use a sprite you could just pick 1 pixel that you want to use since it is downloaded anyway if you go that route.  I posted this as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of some browsers - as far as I can recall, Firefox, Chrome and Safari show nothing while Internet Explorer shows a broken image icon. Short of using Javascript, I don't believe you can override this behaviour.

Comment: At least in FF, you can force the icon with `img:-moz-broken{-moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;}`

Answer (score 1):

The browser does that broken image icon.  It's not something you can change within the code.  I think you'll find that the different browsers handle missing images differently.

What you want to do could be handled differently, though...

Style:

```
div.image-maybe-missing {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url("/images/is-it-there.png");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-maybe-missing">
</div>
```

This will give you an empty box with a red background if the image isn't present.  The width and height of the div needs to match the width and height of the image.

Comment: But IE will still show a red "X" when the original image is not found.

Answer (score 0):

That's a browser-dependent behaviour, but you can't do anything about it. Here are a couple of options:

1) Use JavaScript to add an onerror handler to the image that hides it when it fails to load by settings it to hidden using css (you'll need to have a containing div to apply the background color to as the background color won't show if the image is hdden).

To apply an error handler to every image in the site without jQuery and without modifying the code, you can do this (put this in a script at the end of the page - it won't work if it's in the `<head>` and you can't put it in window.onload or it won't fire before the images have loaded).

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onerror = function() {
        this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

2) Set the image as the css background-image on a div instead of using an `<img>` tag. It's not as semantic, but it won't display a broken image icon if it fails to load, and you can still specify a background color and a label (not an alt tag).

Answer (score 0):

Try **this.remove()** to remove the broken image placeholder:

```
<div class="cell">
  <p>
    <img src="pic.png" onerror="this.remove();" />
  </p>
</div>
```

I use cell divs to preserve layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Another solid way to accomplish this if you are using JavaScript is by creating a function for the onerror** ->

```js
function createImage(image) {
  const avatar = document.createElement("img");
  avatar.src = `${image}`;
    
  avatar.onerror = function () {
    avatar.src = "../../assets/placeholder/avatar.png";
  };
};
```

or as the top-rated comment ->

```html
<img src="../image.png" onerror="this.src='../../assets/images/avatar-placeholder.png';">
```